When I press keys on my keyboard, sometimes it makes a clicking sound?
Okay, so today, I used my laptop, and it was perfectly fine. When I opened a game (played before with no issues happening after), and then got off the game, my keyboard stopped working. Occasionally, when I press a key, some weird clicking noise will sound. I tried using the mousepad lock, it doesn't work anymore. My mouse still works, but nothing else. I dunno if I can add a video link or something to SHOW my problem, but I don't know what to do. My keyboard/under the keys isn't dirty, my laptop worked perfectly fine earlier today. I don't know of it was just a setting I messed with in the game that affected my entire laptop, or which setting it was if that WAS the case, but regardless, I need help. Please!!!

Have you tried rebooting?
